# How to get BinarySecurityToken into the wcf soap request

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I need to sign my soap request to a 3rd party.  The provided an example what the call should look like.  And I am trying, rather unsuccessfully to make this call with wcf. 
I need to make a wcf soap call where the header contains BinarySecurityToken, Signature, and SecurityTokenReference.

Here is the example they sent me (with some of the values omitted) I have a certificate for signing, but I cant for the life of me figure out how to make this work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">

<wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-..omitted.." xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">..omitted..</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>

<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
    <ds:Reference URI="#Body">
      <ds:Transforms>
        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
      </ds:Transforms>
      <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
      <ds:DigestValue>..omitted...</ds:DigestValue>
    </ds:Reference>
  </ds:SignedInfo>
  <ds:SignatureValue>
    ..omitted..
  </ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo><wsse:SecurityTokenReference><wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-..omitted.." ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body wsu:Id="Body"><in0 xmlns="http://test.3rdParty.com">123</in0></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

We ended up with a hotfix from microsoft and few custom classes

Comment: Any chance of including your approach, and hotfix details.

Comment: Sorry, Andrew its been to long and the approach was so convoluted I couldn't for the life of me give you the details

Comment: I have this exact problem. I would hugely appreciate it if you could post the answer on here.

Comment: I am sorry, Ryan, but Microsoft made us a patch specifically for us on this one, I am afraid, we arent allowed to share it.